# Implement trait for closure type alias

Tags: closures, rust, traits, type-alias

I have this closure type alias:

```
type ClosureType = Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>;
```

this trait:

```
trait Trait {
    fn change(&self, y: i32) -> i32;
}
```

and these functions:

```
fn with_one(x: Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> i32 {
    x(1)
}

fn plus_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x+1
}

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(|x: i32|{x+1});
    let b: ClosureType = Box::new(|x: i32|{x+1});
    let c = Box::new(plus_one);
    let d: ClosureType = Box::new(plus_one);
    println!("{}", a.change(1));
    println!("{}", b.change(1));
    println!("{}", c.change(1));
    println!("{}", d.change(1));
    println!("{}", with_one(a));
    println!("{}", with_one(b));
    println!("{}", with_one(c));
    println!("{}", with_one(d));
}
```

When I implement the trait `Trait` for `ClosureType` or for `Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>` which is the same if I understand correctly type aliases:

```
impl Trait for ClosureType {
    fn change(&self, y: i32) -> i32{
        self(y)
    }
}
```

or

```
impl Trait for Box<Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    fn change(&self, y: i32) -> i32{
        self(y)
    }
}
```

for variable `a` I get:

```
<anon>:32:22: 32:31 error: no method named `change` found for type
`Box<[closure <anon>:28:22: 28:35]>` in the current scope 
<anon>:32     println!("{}", a.change(1));
```

and for variable `c`  I get:

```
<anon>:34:22: 34:31 error: no method named `change` found for type
`Box<fn(i32) -> i32 {plus_one}>` in the current scope
<anon>:34     println!("{}", c.change(1));
```

However variables `a` and `c` are accepted from function `with_one(x: Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>) -> i32`, in other words it seems that they have the same type(`Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>`) for function `with_one` but different(`Box<[closure <anon>:24:22: 24:35]>` and `Box<fn(i32) -> i32 {plus_one}`) for `Trait` implementation.

I feel I missing something here but not sure what it is, could you enlighten me?

you can find all the code in [this rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9bfcd27580cf078e0551).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this happens due to automatic coercion (that is, its absence) from a concrete type to a trait object type.

When you call `with_one()`, the compiler is able to understand from the function argument type that you want a trait object and so it inserts automatic coercions:

```
with_one(a as Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>);
with_one(c as Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>);
```

For `b` and `d` these coercions have already happened at their assignment place in `let`s.

For trait methods, however, the compiler does not perform coercions. This is a common behavior around generics (and traits are implemented over generics - their `Self` type is essentially an implicit type parameter for all trait methods). For example, Rust also does not perform deref coercions when using generics:

```
trait MyStringLike {}

impl<'a> MyStringLike for &'a str {}

fn function<T: MyStringLike>(t: T) {}

let s: String = "abcde".into();
function(&s);  // the trait `main::MyStringLike` is not implemented for the type `&collections::string::String`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed by casting a or c as `Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>` works.
Also a typo correction on your answer, under the first block of code is `b` and `d` and not `b` and `c`.